# Problem: building my vue project takes forever

Tags: vue.js

I've built a small vue project with 4 components and I want to build it to upload but it takes forever and building never completes.

I waited for 40 mins and building is not complete.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I would try to stop and build again, If it does not finish in 20s, stop again. Go in your project delete `node_modules` folder and install everything again and try to build.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in comments building of application should finish in few seconds.

One of possible solution is to delete `node_modules` folder and install all deps again. It can help you.

Another possible solution it is to allocate more memory for task:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service build
```

This line will call `node` with increased size of memory (4GB) and will execute building task.

More about of how to serve and build application you can read here -
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#using-the-binary